# c++ Incomplete type error when defining AppServiceConnection with WinRT Console App

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-winrt

I am trying to create a AppServiceConnection but when doing so I get a `Incomplete Type not allowed`

I verified the header file is imported for that class as mention in other stackoverflow questions.

I tried several different attempted to define the AppServieConnection. Am I putting in the wrong place?
The only way it worked was putting it above the main method.

Here is my code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <appmodel.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <appmodel.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace winrt;

using namespace concurrency;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace std;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::AppService;


AppServiceConnection connection_worked; // defining it here works but cannot call any methods from it
int main()
{
    init_apartment();
    Uri uri(L"http://aka.ms/cppwinrt");
    printf("Hello, %ls!\n", uri.AbsoluteUri().c_str());
}

class NewClass {
    private:
        Windows::ApplicationModel::AppService::AppServiceConnection connection{nullptr};
        Windows::ApplicationModel::AppService::AppServiceConnection connection2;
        Windows::ApplicationModel::AppService::AppServiceConnection connection3 = nullptr;
        AppServiceConnection connection4;
        AppServiceConnection connection5 = nullptr;
        AppServiceConnection connection6 = AppServiceConnection();

        IAsyncAction InitializeAppServiceConnection() {
            



        }

    public:
        NewClass() {

        }

    
    

};
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] alongside the exact, unabridged error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, you are missing `AppServiceConnection` header file.

Please add the header file
`#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService.h>`

Comment: The error might be clear, but it's not the error you get when failing to include a header file that defines the projected type (see [Why does my C++/WinRT project get errors of the form “consume_Something: function that returns ‘auto’ cannot be used before it is defined”?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190530-00/?p=102529)).